react-native-video flatlist rendering only 5 videos
i am making a simple video displayer
i am fetching videos data from appwrite data
even if i am using videosdata.js and offline videodata in it
my player just plays 5 videos while i am having 10 video url in my array
please if someone can solve my issue
i am using flatlist to render my video
i was expecting it to be able to display all video in my array
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { NativeSyntheticEvent, NativeScrollEvent } from 'react-native';
import { useRoute, RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';


import initialVideos from './VideoItem'; // Your video items
import service from '../appwrite/dataService';



const App = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState(initialVideos);
  const [currentVideoIndex, setCurrentVideoIndex] = useState(0);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);
  const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);

  const videoRef = useRef<Video>(null);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState<number>(0); // video reference 
  useEffect(()=> {
    const get = async () => {
      try {
         // console.time('getResponse'); // Start the timer
          console.log('inside get');
          
          const dbPosts = await service.getPosts(); // Get the response from getPosts
          if (dbPosts) {
              const postsArray = dbPosts.documents.map((doc, index) => ({
                  id: doc.id,
                  uri: doc.uri,
                  height: doc.height,
                  width: doc.width,
              }));
              console.log('inside dpposts');
              
              if(postsArray){
              await setVideos(postsArray)
                //setIsLoading(false)
                console.log(videos);
                
              }
              else{
                get()
              }
            
              console.log(postsArray); // Log the array of posts
          }

          
          //console.timeEnd('getResponse'); // End the timer and log the elapsed time
      } catch (error) {
          console.log("Appwrite service :: get :: error", error);
          get()
      }
  }
  
  get()
  
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    const loadDataAsync = async () => {
      // Example of loading data (e.g., video playback times) from AsyncStorage
      try {
        const storedIndex = await AsyncStorage.getItem('currentVideoIndex');
        if (storedIndex !== null) {
          setCurrentVideoIndex(parseInt(storedIndex, 10));
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // reading error
      }
    };

    loadDataAsync();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Example of saving the current video index to AsyncStorage
    const saveDataAsync = async () => {
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('currentVideoIndex', currentVideoIndex.toString());
      } catch (e) {
        // saving error
      }
    };

    saveDataAsync();
  }, [currentVideoIndex]);

  

  const handlePress = () => {
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
  };

  const handleScroll = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
    const contentOffsetY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
    const nextVideoIndex = Math.round(contentOffsetY / screenHeight);

    if (nextVideoIndex !== currentVideoIndex) {
      setCurrentVideoIndex(nextVideoIndex);
      setIsPlaying(true); // Ensure video plays when scrolled to a new one
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        ref={flatListRef}
        data={videos}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          const aspectRatio = item.width / item.height;
          const isLandscape = aspectRatio > 1;
          

         return (<>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress} style={[styles.videoContainer, isLandscape && styles.landscapeVideoContainer]}>
            < View style={[styles.videoWrapper, isLandscape && styles.landscapeVideoWrapper]}>
            <Video
              ref={videoRef}
              source={{ uri: item.uri }}
              style={[styles.video, isLandscape && styles.landscapeVideo]}
              resizeMode="cover"
              paused={!isPlaying || index !== currentVideoIndex}
              repeat
            />
            </View>
          
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </>
          

        )}}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        pagingEnabled
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  videoContainer: {
    aspectRatio: 9/16 ,
    width: '100%',
    position: 'relative',
  },
  landscapeVideoContainer: {
    aspectRatio: 9 / 16, // Landscape aspect ratio
  },
  video: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  videoWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  landscapeVideoWrapper: {
    transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }], // Rotate by 90 degrees for landscape mode
  },
  landscapeVideo: {
    // Example landscape video style
    width: '100%',
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9, // or any other aspect ratio you deem appropriate
  },

  

});

export default App;`

